# How to define a generic in Typescript that forces an index signature

Tags: typescript

In Typescript, to give an object an index signature, you can define it in one of two ways depending on your needs. Let's say I have an `Indexable` interface and an `EmployeeDir` type.

```js
type EmployeeType = "contractor" | "permanent";

type EmployeeDir = {
    [key in EmployeeType]: any
}

interface Indexable {
    [key: string]: any;
}
```

I know I can use a generic that accepts either of these two values like so:

```js
function limited<T extends EmployeeDir | Indexable>(val: T): T {
    return val;
}
```

But how do I enforce that the given type *has* any type of index signature? I don't care what the index signature is, I just want to make sure that it *has* one. How would I go about that?

```js
// What can I put here to allow any object type at all as
// long has it has a signature definition?
function anything<T /* extends ...*/>(val: T): T {
    return val;
}
```

I'm probably searching for the wrong thing since all my results keep leading to the "object has no index signature" error, which is not what I want.

Comment: It seems like you should just be able to extend `Indexable`, no? `EmployeeType` (and any other valid indexing) will be a subset of `[key: string]` due to JS' requirement that object keys be strings.

Comment: `EmployeeDir` doesn't have an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types); it's a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) that evaluates to `{ contractor: any; permanent: any; }`.  Mapped types are not index signatures (even if the syntax looks similar), so I'm not sure what you're asking for.

Comment: Thanks for that @jcalz, that actually helped clarify things for me, I can look at `keyof` now for that. @ChrisHeald, isn't `[key: number]` also a valid indexing method in TS? How could I specify allowing either string or number indexes?

Comment: Wait, then if that's the case, I can just do `{[key: string]: any} | {[key: number]: any}` and that'd cover the only possible index signatures since I learned that mapped types don't have them. Thank you both for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57894999/how-to-define-a-generic-in-typescript-that-forces-an-index-signature#comment102211496_57894999) for the clarification. In my example, `EmployeeDir` doesn't have an index signature; it's a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) that evaluates to:

```js
interface EmployeeDir {
    contractor: any;
    permanent: any;
}
```

The only two possible index signatures are `{[key: string]: any}` and `{[key: number]: any}`. Which would let me have something along the lines of:

```js
interface StringIndexable {
    [key: string]: any;
}

interface NumberIndexable {
    [key: number]: any;
}

function anything<T extends NumberIndexable | StringIndexable>(val: T): T {
    let key: keyof T;

    for (key in val) {
        let value = val[key];
    }

    return val;
}
```